# How to create secured files in Puppet5 with Hiera?

Tags: puppet, hiera

I want to create SSL certificate and try to secure this operation. 
I am using Puppet 5.5.2 and gem hiera-eyaml.

Created simple manifest

```
cat /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp

package { 'tree':
  ensure => installed,
}
package { 'httpd':
  ensure => installed,
}
$filecrt = lookup('files')
create_resources( 'file', $filecrt )
```

Hiera config

```
---
version: 5
defaults:
  # The default value for "datadir" is "data" under the same directory as the hiera.yaml
  # file (this file)
  # When specifying a datadir, make sure the directory exists.
  # See https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/environments_about.html for further details on environments.
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "Secret data: per-node, per-datacenter, common"
    lookup_key: eyaml_lookup_key # eyaml backend
    paths:
      - "nodes/%{facts.fqdn}.eyaml"
      - "nodes/%{trusted.certname}.eyaml"  # Include explicit file extension
      - "location/%{facts.whereami}.eyaml"
      - "common.eyaml"
    options:
      pkcs7_private_key: /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/keys/private_key.pkcs7.pem
      pkcs7_public_key:  /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/eyaml/keys/public_key.pkcs7.pem
  - name: "YAML hierarchy levels"
    paths:
      - "common.yaml"
      - "nodes/%{facts.fqdn}.yaml"
      - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}.yaml"
```

And common.yaml

```
---
files:
'/etc/httpd/conf/server.crt':
ensure: present
mode: '0600'
owner: 'root'
group: 'root'
content: 'ENC[PKCS7,{LOT_OF_STRING_SKIPPED}+uaCmcHgDAzsPD51soM+AIkIlv0ANpUXzBpwM3tqQ3ysFtz81S0xuVbKvslK]'
```

But have en error while applying manifest

```
Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, create_resources(): second argument must be a hash (file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp, line: 12, column: 1) on node test1.com
```

I really dont know what to do )

Comment: your encrypted data need to be in files with extension with eyaml and you are using the normal one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be that the indentation in `common.yaml` isn't right - currently, `file` will be `null` rather than a hash, which explains the error message. Also, the file should be called `common.eyaml`, otherwise the `ENC` string won't be decrypted. Try

```
---
files:
  '/etc/httpd/conf/server.crt':
    ensure: present
    mode: '0600'
    owner: 'root'
    group: 'root'
    content: 'ENC[PKCS7{LOTS_OF_STRING_SKIPPED}UXzBpwM3tqQ3ysFtz81S0xuVbKvslK]'
```

There is an online YAML parser at http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/ if you want to see the difference the indentation makes.

Answer (score 0):

Found another solution.

Its was a problem with lookup and hashes. When I have multiply lines in hiera hash, I must specify them https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.5/function.html#lookup

So i decided use only 'content' variable to lookup

```
cat site.pp
$filecrt = lookup('files')

file { 'server.crt':
  ensure  => present,
  path    => '/etc/httpd/conf/server.crt',
  content => $filecrt,
  owner   => 'root',
  group   => 'root',
  mode    => '0600',
}
```

and Hiera

```
---
files:'ENC[PKCS7{LOT_OF_STRING_SKIPPED}+uaCmcHgDAzsPD51soM+AIkIlv0ANpUXzBpwM3tqQ3ysFtz81S0xuVbKvslK]'
```